# Getting connection errors to in-memory neo4j instance during testing using the new spring-data-neo4j 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Using the release versions, this application code works. However, switching to the newer snapshots, I am now getting exceptions.

The exception messages lead me to think a config change is needed to get my test cases working again, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what they would need to be.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My test case is using annotations:

- @SpringBootTest
- @EnableAutoConfiguration
- @AutoConfigureDataNeo4j

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.PermissionDeniedDataAccessException: Unsupported authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled.; Error code 'Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized'
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateImpl(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:105) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:83) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:187) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient.access$400(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:59) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.one(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:298) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate$DefaultExecutableQuery.getSingleResult(Neo4jTemplate.java:525) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.Neo4jQueryExecution$DefaultQueryExecution.execute(Neo4jQueryExecution.java:53) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractNeo4jQuery.execute(AbstractNeo4jQuery.java:68) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.0-M2.jar:2.4.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.0-M2.jar:2.4.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:151) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.0-M2.jar:2.4.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.0-M2.jar:2.4.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.0-M2.jar:2.4.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.findByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.0-M2.jar:5.3.0-M2]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

In some variations of my testing, I get:
"Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0"

Answer (score 1):

What are your application properties?

The syntax changed for SDN6, but might not have made it into the docs

See:

https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-sdn-ogm-tips/blob/master/examples/sdn6/src/main/resources/application.properties

ah it actually has it in the readme (but not yet in the docs):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j

Also in the boot docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-neo4j